# Proof of the Kuratowski Formalization

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, set-theory

I recently saw the Kuratowski Formalization of an ordered pair, and decided to take a crack at proving it does what it says. I tried to consider the 3 cases of $(a,b)=(c,d)$, either $a=b=c=d$, $a=b, c \neq d$ (without loss of generality), and $a\neq b, c \neq d$.

Some things I'm concerned about:

In the $\implies $ direction, I assume $(a,b)=(c,d)$ and then in case 1 I also assume $a=b,c\neq d$. This leads to a contradiction to one of my assumptions (I think to $(a,b)=(c,d)$) but I don't know how to tell for sure. (Contradicting the first assumption $(a,b)=(c,d)$ would be best since it would prove the theorem vacuously in this case.)

Any other comments or tips would be appreciated, I'm a bit rusty.

[image: Proof of the Kuratowski Formalization]

edit: The last sentence of the proof should read: Therefore $d=b$.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with *"both of these sets have at least one element and at most two"*, plus all those statements that are close in spirit. Let $A := \{ \{a\}, \{a,b\} \}$ and $B:=\{\{c\},\{c,d\}\}$. How do the elements of $A$ and $B$ you are referring to look like? Do they look like $\{a\}$ or rather as $a$?

Comment: I mean for example, if $a=b$, then $\{a,b\}$ only really has 1 element and $\{a,b\}=\{a\}$. Also, the elements of $A$ and $B$ are sets, so they look as I have written them. (Some people would thus call $A,B$ "collections" or "families of sets".

Comment: Ok then, for example, how you start Case 1 looks strange to me: you should actually start by assuming wlog that $A := \{ \{a\}\}$, which in turn implies by definition of set that $a=b$. You  proceed the other way around. Same applies to Case 2.

Comment: I made 2 assumptions in case 1, $a=b$ and $c\neq d$ which guaranteed that exactly one set had 2 (distinct) elements, and one set had 1. I could have done it the way you described by assuming $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}=\{\{a\}\} \land \{\{c\},\{c,d\}\} \neq \{\{c\}\}$. However, considering $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}=\{\{a\}\}  \iff a=b$, these two statements are equivalent, so its just a matter of style. Perhaps the way you suggest is clearer to the idea of the proof, although both ways are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to prove it: if $(a,b)=(c,d)$, then intersection $\bigcap(a,b) = \{a\}\cap \{a,b\}$ of  $(a,b)$ and the intersection of $(c,d)$ are same. Therefore we have $\{a\}=\{c\}$ and we have $a=c$.

Now consider the union $\bigcup(a,b) = \{a,b\}$, so we have $\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$. If $a=b$, then $\{a\}=\{a,d\}$ so $a=d$. Otherwise, so if $a\neq b$, then we can take difference by $\{a\}$ in both sides of the equality and we get $\{b\}=\{d\}$.

Comment: I made a typo in my proof. Your 2nd para needs to deduce $d=b$. Rewriting it, I have:
By assumption $(a,b)=(c,d)$. Thus $\cup(a,b)=\cup(c,d)$. In the first para we deduced $a=c$, thus $\cup(a,b)=\cup(a,d)$, so $\{a,b\}=\{a,d\}$, so $d=a\lor b$. So we have 2 cases:
Case 1: If $d=a$ then $\{a,b\}=\{a\}$ so $a=b$. Thus $a=b=d$ so $b=d$. Case 2: $d=b$, done. Neat approach, thanks!

Comment: @EvanRosica There is a typo in my previous answer. I fixed it.

Comment: How did you get  $\bigcup(a,b) = \{a,b\}$, so we have $\{a,c\}=\{a,d\}$?

Comment: @EvanRosica Formally, $\bigcup(a,b)=\bigcup \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ is $\{a\}\cup \{a,b\}$.

Comment: I understand how $\cup (a,b) = \{a,b\}$, but not how $\cup (a,b) = \{a,b\} \implies \{a,c\}=\{a,d\}$

Comment: @EvanRosica There was an abuse of symbols. You can see that $(a,c)=(b,d)$ implies $\bigcup (a,c)=\bigcup(b,d)$. Now we can apply $\bigcup(x,y)=\{x,y\}$ to this equality.

Comment: But we assumed $(a,b)=(c,d)$, not $(a,c)=(b,d)$, so how do you know $(a,c)=(b,d)$?

Comment: @EvanRosica Oh, this is my confusion... I will fix this.